# Redis : Storing same values in multiple keys and controlling these using dependencies

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

We are using StackExchange.Redis

We are a Grid based application where Grids represent appointments for a single day. On one component it can be display appointments for entire day whereas on another component it can be display appointments for entire day but only for one location and similarly on a third component it can be display appointments for entire day for one room only in a location.

Best possible approach would have been storing each appointment as a key and then having indexes of these different display templates so that they can be easily queried.

However the application has been coded around appointments for a single day. So single day is a key and all appointments are value of that Key. This is stored in Redis as string. Every time even a single item changes, the entire List of items in extracted from Redis and a new List of items is set. This involves a lot of serialization/deserialization as well as network. This cannot be changed.

Now in case we need to get items for only one room, we need to get data for entire day and then filter it on the component. This wastes CPU cycles as well as a lot of unnecessary data travels over the wire.

If we store these as 3 different Keys, one for each component, first of all it is duplication of data secondly it would be tough to maintain as any change to even a single item will have to be done to all keys.

Is there any better way of doing this? Please suggest possible approaches